# 2D racetrack collision bounce using angle of reflection (bounce angle)

Tags: c#, collision-detection, software-engineering, graphics-programming, color

I am currently working on a race game where I want to define the collision of my vehicle with the outer and inner borders of the track.

If that happens to be the case I want to vehicle to bounce of the track but still move forward using the angle of reflection.

My racetrack looks like this: 
[image]

I am wondering if the implementation is possible especially since I have curves in my track. I was thinking of defining the inner and outer boundaries using color recognition, in this case white and red, and then check for collision.

Thank you.

Update 1:

To execute what @Zebraman suggested I plan on doing the following:
To get the pixel color under the vehicle I think I have to iterate over all pixels and then check the colors of the pixels infront of the vehicle to make the vehicle bounce in the reflection angle.

How to perform the color check is for me still a question now. Hope Anatole could help. @Zebraman provided an explanation of how to get the pixels color. I don't understand it yet.

Hopefully someone would be able to explain.

Update 2:

I am going to use the following code to detect pixel collision:

```
static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA,
                            Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
        {
            // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
            int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
            int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
            int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
            int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

            // Check every point within the intersection bounds
            for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
            {
                for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
                {
                    // Get the color of both pixels at this point
                    Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
                                         (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                    Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
                                         (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

                    // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
                    if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                    {
                        // then an intersection has been found
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // No intersection found
            return false;
        }
```

Could anyone point me where to next?

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate to get a good enough reflection angle. Remember, most players (if not all) don't go over game footage frame-by-frame doing pixel measurements to check whether the angles match up.

So, first thing you should do is to polygonize the racetrack. This can be done by an algorithm, but if you have only relatively few levels, then [writing the tool may require more time than it saves over doing it by hand](https://xkcd.com/1319/) (This doesn't mean that you should just use a text-editor and estimate where the points are, you should write a program that helps you, but don't create an image analyzer). If we take your original example, the polygon would look something like the following (I wasn't very exact, but you get the point):

[image]

Now we can do the collision detection. Due to the way your cars look like, you could take a circle that fully encloses your car and do a collision check on each side of the polygon separately. From [this site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) we see, that to determine whether a circle and a line intersects, we need the start and end points of the line (`(x1; y1)` and `(x2; y2)` in order) and the radius of the circle (`r`).

If the formula

```
r^2 * ((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2) - x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
```

is greater than or equal to 0, the circle and the line intersect. You can also get the intersection's position, but it's not necessary to calculate it if your cars don't go with a relatively high speed (more than around the car's size every frame).

So, now we know which line segment the car hit. Next thing we need to now is in which direction it bounces us. Luckily there's also a way to find this out, but it involves a bit of vector math, mainly the dot product. Let's take the following example:

[image]

Here line `AB` is the line segment, **d** is the car's direction and **e** is the direction you want to find. First you'll have to convert line `AB` to a vector, let's call it **c** for convenience. First you'll have to get the normal vector of **c**. The normal vector is a vector with a length of 1, that's perpendicular to **c**. You can get it by taking the `x` and `y` components of **c** and creating the vector `(y; -x)`, which is the rotated version of it, and normalizing it. Let's call this vector **n**. Now, to get the actual reflected direction, take **d** and the newly created **n** and using the formula:

```
e = d - 2 * (d ⋅ n) * n
```

And voilá, you got your new direction.

Comment: I have only one level with the shown track. I made the track using a tiles package in inkscape. This luckily means that I can change the border of the track to a colour of my choosing. I was thinking of doing this and add the image to the game (in the background) and then use it to check for collision. Would you recommend going down this path or drawPolygons in C#? In your last example you are saying using the direction of the car (or position I guess) to calculate the new direction, wouldn't a similar calculation work and deliver the same desired result if I used the velocity?

Comment: @AhmedAli It would, in fact, it would be your best option. You shouldn't use pixel based collisions, you can't really decide the new direction from those

Comment: Thank you  for you quick reply. I will start working on editing the colour of the track to one colour through out the track. Then I will figure out how to check for collision between the circle and this one colour line. To clear it up for myself, you said don't use pixel based collision, how am I supposed to check if my circle (surrounding the car) is colliding with the one colour track border (line) in the image/ hidden background? Thanks again.

Comment: @Ahmed as I said, you should polygonize the area. See my image above.

Comment: Sorry for asking stupid questions. You have draw polygons in the track by drawing lines if I am not mistaken. Say I do the same, how do I get the recognition done in c#. How do I define the polygon(s) as the border and use it to check for collision. Again sorry

Comment: @Ahmed that polygon is just a representation, you should just store it as a list of points (vectors).

Comment: I have stored the points into a list. I am also able to check for a collision and use your formula. However, I am using vehicles (other than on the image) that are more rectangular. Surrounding them with circles leave empty spaces that are taken into account when checking for collision. In other words empty spaces return true when hitting the borders. How can I check for collision in case of a rectangular vehicle? What formula(s) do I need?

Comment: @Ahmed I'm happy to hear that you succeeded with the algorithm. For rectangular objects you could a) define the edges as lines and do line-line collisions with the outside polygon or b) define the rectangle (or another polygon) as a series of points, then do a ray-lije intersection with the road polygon's lines where the ray is the cars direction and the origins are the points. I personally recommend the latter

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Could you elaborate more on how to do a ray-line intersection? Some (pseudo)code would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Ahmed thinking about it, it's actually better to do a [line-line](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line–line_intersection) intersection where one line is the polygon's edge, and the other is made from point and the point made by adding the velocity vector to the point.

Comment: One line is made by the points in a polygon (array with points). and the other is made by a point and point+velocityVector. Which point in this case? A point on my rectangle? Or something else?

Comment: @Ahmed You need to do it for every corner if the rectangle, the point is a corner.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just noticed that looping through my intersect method for inner track and outer, checking if vehicle is colliding slows down the game. Is there another way instead of using a for loop? Also when checking for collision it detects it correctly when my vehicle moves vertically towards the polygon, if it is heading for a vertical line (moving horizontally) it only recognizes the collision when my vehicles center point intersects halfway with the polygon, It is as if my rectangular vehicle doesn't take the rotationtransform even though I have it before DrawRectangle.

Comment: @Ahmed do you transform the points too?

Comment: Yes I am using graphics.Transform and then store it in a Matrix.

Comment: I have gotten a little further. Now I am facing an issue where when my vehicle collides it gets reflected but then my back gets flagged as collided and so my vehicle remains reflecting until I can get it out. The vehicle soon after "flies out" from the track. I can get it back but with collision detection on, it takes a few attempts. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible but it's not simple.

Your velocity after collision will essentially  be v - n. v being velocity, n being the normal of the wall scaled by your alignment with said normal.

In order to get the correct reflection you will need to know the "normal" of the wall you collide with. There's a couple ways to do this.

The fastest (in runtime) way would be to create a texture that holds this information. That way when you use your color detection to check for collisions you can use the same information to get the normal. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any tools that will do this for you automatically so it's a pain to set up, but easy to work with once done. This is often done using a normal map. But since you're only working in 2 dimensions there would be no blue.

[image: o]

Each pixel represents a vector with red as the x component and green as the y component.

The other option is to calculate it n the fly. This would require your code to be able to recognize an edge, then use that calculate the tangent, then find the perpendicular line.

You would have to do the math for something that looks like this
[image]

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "normal"? Also if it helps I have my velocity as a vector. I can also retrieve the angle (0-360)of my vehicle on the screen. What I had in mind is use it when checking for collision such that velocityX reverses when the vehicle hits the top or bottom border and velocityY reverses when it hits the right or left border of the track. If I am making things more complicated for my self, I would appreciate it if you point that out.

Comment: A normal is the vector that is perpendicular to a surface. If you're already using vectors for velocity, it's probably easier to use them for everything. You're on the right track, but as you've already expressed, adding curves makes things much harder.

Comment: how would you suggest handeling this with curves present? Would I get anywhere with the curves if i continue down the road I am on? Or should I tackle this in a different way? If yes, which way would it be?

Comment: My initial answer covers how to handle the track with curves. Regardless of how you want to proceed. You do NEED the normal of the wall, whether it's represented in rotation or vector format doesn't really matter. Once you have that, the actual calculations for reflection are rather trivial.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Sorry for sounding amateur but how you provided two methods to calculate the normal. One is based on color and the other on the fly. Could you give me a simple example on each or either. Appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I started the implementation for the colour check. As you said blue is not present since it is only 2d. Am I supposed to use the track I have to check for red and green or do I need to create another map where those colours are actually present? In my implementation I plan on iterating over each pixel in my Bitmap. Should I just iterate over, in my case, just the white and red coloured pixel? And then Calculate the normal from each of those pixels? Again sorry for any basic questions.

Comment: I have updated my initial post. Hope you could take a look. I am new to the world of c#